# Cual es el significado de "...args" en el argumento de una funcion en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

Leyendo un poco de codigo en Javascript me he topado con esto:

```
router.route('/:id')
.put((...args) => controller.update(...args))
.get((...args) => controller.findById(...args));
```

Alguien tiene claro lo que  **...args** significa?

Comment: Parámetros rest: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como un colega comentó a tu pregunta, son [Parámetros Rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest), en donde simplemente este (`...args`) es un *objeto* de tipo `array` que va desde `0` hasta `args.length`, ejemplo:

```js
function fun1(...args) {
  console.log(args.length);
}

fun1();        // 0
fun1(5);       // 1
fun1(5, 6, 7); // 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Complementando lo que señala @Naos, los "puntos suspensivos" son el [Operador Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator), el cual permite especificar que la función tratará lo contenido en ese parámetro como un array, o más precisamente un iterable.

Antiguamente eso se hacía utilizando `arguments` y en tu pregunta se comportaría exactamente igual: un array con todos los parámetros entregados a la función.

Sin embargo el spread operator además permite hacer cosas que antes requerían una vuelta rebuscada aplicando array_slice sobre arguments. Por ejemplo, declarar una función de la que conoces su primer parámetro, pero desconoces todo el resto:

```js
function marcavehiculo(vehiculo, ...marcas) {
   console.log('Quiero comprar un '+vehiculo+' de alguna de las siguentes marcas');
   console.log(marcas);
}

marcavehiculo('automóvil','chevrolet','peugeot','citroen');
marcavehiculo('avión','boeing','airbus');
```